# Scala type bounds behaviour (method vs class)

Tags: scala, generics, types, bounds

Probably an easy one for Scala gurus. I'm reading up on type bound constraints and wondering if I'm missing something, as I'm seeing a slightly unexpected behaviour. Let's say we have three types A,B,C in a hierarchy like this, for which we're experimenting with type bounds:

```
class A {
}

class B extends A {
}

class C extends B {
}

class MyList1 { // T super B
  def add[T >: B](a: T): Unit = {}
}

class MyList2 { // T extends B
  def add[T <: B](a: T): Unit = {}
}

class MyList3[T >: B] { // T super B
  def add(a: T): Unit = {}
}

class MyList4[T <: B] { // T extends B
  def add(a: T): Unit = {}
}

object BoundsClass {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val l1 = new MyList1
    l1.add(new A) 
    l1.add(new B)
    l1.add(new C) // why is this allowed??

    val l2 = new MyList2
    // l2.add(new A) // not allowed (OK)
    l2.add(new B)
    l2.add(new C)

    val l3a = new MyList3[A]
    val l3b = new MyList3[B]
    // val l3c = new MyList3[C] // not allowed (OK)

    // val l4a = new MyList4[A] // not allowed (OK)
    val l4b = new MyList4[B]
    val l4c = new MyList4[C]
  }

}
```

The collections are behaving as expected for all except one case, see l1.add(new C); not causing a compilation error. Why is this allowed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not claiming to be a scala guru, but I'll take a stab at this.

You've defined your type hierarchy along the lines of `A >: B >: C`, so you can do stuff like

```
val aa: A = new A
val ab: A = new B
val ac: A = new C

val bb: B = new B
val bc: B = new C

val cc: C = new C
```

just like you could say `val a: Any = new Whatever`.

So when you try to add a `new C` to `l1`, it gets treated like a `B` instance because that is the closest available version of itself that conforms to the method's type bounds.

Comment: If tried these two: "val c1 : A = new C" and "val c2 : C = new C". I think the second shouldn't (as in collection "l3c") because the constraint is "T is supertype of B", but c2 is clearly a subtype here no? But again there are no errors...

Comment: `c2` is an *instance* of `C`, and because of how inheritance works, it is also an instance of `B` (and `A`), so it's not an error.

Answer (score 0):

Lower bounds are not useful when used in that way. You cannot enforce a value parameter to have a lower bound because, according to the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), you must be able to use an instance of a subclass anywhere an instance of a class is required. Therefore, your code compiles because `new C` can be seen as an instance of `B`.

Generally, it is not useful to put a lower bound on a value parameter of a method because of that reason. Lower bounds are definitely more useful in your second case, where you bound the type parameter of a class. All type parameters are resolved at compile type and, as such, you can expect the compiler to yield compiler errors in your second case. You can find a more concrete example of lower bound usage [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/137).